# Android app problems with nearby connection

Tags: android, android-things, google-nearby

I would like to learn more about Nearby in app programming. For that, I downloaded this code on GitHub  https://github.com/PaulTR/NearbyConnections2.0Sample. My problem is, that when I want to send a message the mobile app crashes. It seems to be, that the Android Thing device is not really connected to the phone.

Failure:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.tutsplus.nearbyconnections2, PID: 10951
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4732)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22479)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4727)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22479) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbc.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbl.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbd.zze(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcnr.sendPayload(Unknown Source)
                      at com.tutsplus.nearbyconnections2.MainActivity.sendPayload(MainActivity.java:122)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4727) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22479) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6623) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Did anybody have an idea what the problem is?

Best wishes Thorsten

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet` self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setGoogleApiClient() {
    if (googleApiClient != null)
        return;
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}
```

By implementing `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and
        `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` you will be able to detect is `GoogleApiClient` successfully connected or connection failed for some reason. Also before performing your action to avoid possible crash you can again simply check is `GoogleApiClient` connected or not:

```
if (!googleApiClient.isConnected())
            googleApiClient.connect();
else
// perform action
```